# What's the difference in Golang to run a function with or without go

Tags: go

I am new to Go. My question is what's the difference to run a function with or without Go. For example in a .go file I have one test() function, when I call this function what's the difference for "test()" and "go test()".

Comment: The question is "what is a goroutine". Have a look at https://gobyexample.com/goroutines .

Comment: If you are new to Go than take the Tour of Go https://tour.golang.org, then play around and take the tour a second time. Then ask on SO.

Comment: @nilsmagnus Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`test()` will run when you call it. `go test()` will run asynchronously on its own completely independent of `test()`.

If you have a program like this:

```
func main() {
   test("bob")
   go test("sue")
}

func test(msg string) {
  fmt.Printf("hello %v", msg)
}
```

You will only see output

> hello bob

since the `main` function execution jumps right through to the end. There is nothing waiting for `go test("sue")` to complete since it's its own independent function.

You can block for `go test("sue")` by putting in a `time.Sleep` or a command line input with `fmt.Scanln(&input)`

[Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/je5lifQO2S)